# Problems with scatterplot error bars in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a question about how I can do a scatterplot with error bars. I´m working with stable isotopes so I have data on D13C and D15N for faunal samples. I want to obtain a plot like this one (without convex hulls) attached (target)target.png

But on the contrary I obtain a plot like this (CNPlot)CNPlot.png
I´m using this script :

```
a<-read.table("Means.txt", header = TRUE)
theme_set(theme_classic(base_size = 16))
ggplot(a, aes(x=D13C, y=D15N)) +
geom_errorbar(aes(ymax=D13C+D13C.ds, ymin=D13C-D13C.ds), width=0.15,alpha=.8)+
geom_errorbarh(aes(xmax=D15N+D15N.ds, xmin=D15N-D15N.ds), height=0.15,alpha=.8)+  
  geom_point(aes(shape=Species),fill="white",size=4) +
  geom_point(aes(color=Species,fill=Species,shape=Species),size=4, alpha = .5) +
  scale_color_manual(values=c("black","dodgerblue1","coral4","darkorchid"))+
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("black","dodgerblue1","coral4","darkorchid"))+
  scale_shape_manual(values=c(21,23,22,24))+
 labs(title=NULL,
       subtitle=NULL,
       caption=NULL,
       x=expression(paste(delta^{13}, "Ccol(‰)")),      
       y=expression(paste(delta^{15}, "N(‰)")))
```

and I have two datasets but I´m using the one named Means but I have another one named CN_fauna where I included the raw data

Means:

```
Species    D13C    D13C.ds    D15N    D15N.ds
Bird    -16.4    7.1    7.6    1.5
SH    -18.5    1.7    5.5    2.7
CH    -14.8    2.9    8.8    0.6
Deer    -19.2    0.7    4.8    1.04
```

CN_fauna:

```
taxa    D13C    D15N
Bird    -24.1    7.9
Bird    -9.9    9
Bird    -15.2    5.9
SH    -17.0    9.6
SH    -16.6    7.3
SH    -20.3    4.6
SH    -20.3    2.6
SH    -20.3    2.7
SH    -18.6    6.6
CH    -16.9    9.4
CH    -11.5    8.2
CH    -16.1    8.8
Deer    -18.6    3.0
Deer    -19.1    6.0
Deer    -18.3    5.4
Deer    -17.9    5.4
Deer    -19.2    5.6
Deer    -20.4    5.6
Deer    -19.5    6.1
Deer    -20.3    5.9
Deer    -18.7    5.4
Deer    -19.7    3.8
Deer    -19.2    3.4
Deer    -19.9    4.1
Deer    -18.4    4.3
Deer    -20.1    4.1
```

I do not understand why the scales of the error barplots are different in my plot, any help is more than welcome.

Comment: Welcome to SO! While your question already is quite close to a MRE I would still suggest to have a look at how to provide [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). In particular, if you want to post your data(sets), type `dput(NAME_OF_DATASET)` into the console and copy the output starting with `structure(....` into your post. Also, something went wrong when you added the image of your plot.

Answer (score 0):

Not to take away from the sage advice that @stefan provided (reproducible questions get better responses faster)...

I could be wrong, but I think your errorbar data is on the wrong axis. Is that what you were trying to create?

[image]

If so, you need to change your `xmin` to `ymin` and so on for the two errorbar layers. It would look something like this:

```
ggplot(Means, aes(x = D13C, y = D15N)) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(xmax = D13C + D13C.ds, 
                    xmin = D13C - D13C.ds), width=0.15,alpha=.8)+
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymax = D15N + D15N.ds, 
                    ymin = D15N - D15N.ds), height=0.15,alpha=.8)+  
  geom_point(aes(shape=Species),fill="white",size=4) +
  geom_point(aes(color=Species,fill=Species,shape=Species),size=4, alpha = .5) +
  scale_color_manual(values=c("black","dodgerblue1","coral4","darkorchid"))+
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("black","dodgerblue1","coral4","darkorchid"))+
  scale_shape_manual(values=c(21,23,22,24))+
  labs(title=NULL,
       subtitle=NULL,
       caption=NULL,
       x=expression(paste(delta^{13}, "Ccol(‰)")),      
       y=expression(paste(delta^{15}, "N(‰)")))
```

Comment: Dear stefan and Kat thank you very much for your help, suggestions, and clarifications. For future posts, I´ll follow in detail the guidelines. Regarding my example, yes, there was an error, the x and y axes were confused when calling the errorbar functions. Again thanks for your help.

All best,

Paolo